# steps done by Visual studio while running a mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to know the steps done by the visual studio while run a MVC application,means sequence of file read by the VS when I press F5?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/741228/MVC-Application-Lifecycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it calls Global.asax file. Maps all the things and starting elements are initialised. Then the request goes to the controller & the controller gets data from model parses it into view & responses with the appropriate View being rendered with data from model.

Comment: when web.config file called?

Comment: Web.Config is not called. Only the values are retrieved from it as its an XML file for storing configuration of our app